# What do values mean in inode column (proc/net/tcp(6))?

Tags: tcp, inode, uid, proc

This is a piece of /proc/net/tcp file:

> sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
>
> 6: 1904A8C0:AC35 9603020A:1ED0 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 10055 0 8506 2 c1624900 129 0 0 10 -1
> 7: 1904A8C0:E8C4 13A11C1F:0050 06 00000000:00000000 03:00001390
> 00000000     0        0 0 3 d6267780

Can anyone explain me what do values mean in the inode column? I`m intrested in two cases.

> 8506 2 c1624900 129 0 0 10 -1
>
> 0    3 d6267780

I only know first value is inode number (unique file number).

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27659460/694576

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the inode of a TCP socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659460/how-do-i-find-the-inode-of-a-tcp-socket)

Answer (score 0):

linux-2.6.35.6/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c

```
2358     seq_printf(f, "%4d: %08X:%04X %08X:%04X %02X %08X:%08X %02X:%08lX "
2359             "%08X %5d %8d %lu %d %p %lu %lu %u %u %d%n",
2360         i, src, srcp, dest, destp, sk->sk_state,
2361         tp->write_seq - tp->snd_una,
2362         rx_queue,
2363         timer_active,
2364         jiffies_to_clock_t(timer_expires - jiffies),
2365         icsk->icsk_retransmits,
2366         sock_i_uid(sk),
2367         icsk->icsk_probes_out,
2368         sock_i_ino(sk),
2369         atomic_read(&sk->sk_refcnt), sk, 
2370         jiffies_to_clock_t(icsk->icsk_rto),
2371         jiffies_to_clock_t(icsk->icsk_ack.ato),
2372         (icsk->icsk_ack.quick << 1) | icsk->icsk_ack.pingpong,
2373         tp->snd_cwnd,
2374         tcp_in_initial_slowstart(tp) ? -1 : tp->snd_ssthresh,
2375         len);
```